# How was this equation derived?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

[image]

Does anyone know how the equation in red was derived?

Comment: Write $t = \cos(\theta /4) / \sin(\theta /4)$ and simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part:

$$\cos\theta=\cos^2\frac\theta2-\sin^2\frac\theta2=\left(\cos^2\frac\theta4-\sin^2\frac\theta4\right)^2-4\sin^2\frac\theta4\cos^2\frac\theta4.$$

Second part:

$$\cos^2\frac\theta4=\frac1{1+\tan^2\frac\theta4}=\frac1{1+t^2},\\
\sin^2\frac\theta4=\tan^2\frac\theta4\cos^2\frac\theta4=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}.$$

---

But $t=\tan\frac\theta4$, not $\cot\frac\theta4$ nor $\arctan\frac\theta4$ !

Comment: I got this question from a book. "Differential Geometry - Martin Lipschultz"

Comment: @Isaac: obviously. But that doesn't make $t=\text{Tan}^{-1}(\theta/4)$.